# Does EDOPro support the duel coasters ruleset?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

The Duel Coaster was introduced in **Yu-Gi-Oh! ZEXAL** *episode 51:* "Roller Duel", and is a special type of duel that takes place on a roller coaster.

There are special spots on the track, with Spell and Trap Card markings. If a Duelist goes over one of these spots, they will activate the card's effect.
Trap Points have effects that inflict Effect Damage while Spell Points have effects that let you gain Life Points.

In addition the special spots the rules are changed to

- *Life Points don't reset every time there's a new Duel.*
- *There are no turns. Duelists may Normal Summon monsters and activate Spell and Trap Cards whenever they wish.*
- *Draw Phases are conducted only when a Duelist hits a Draw Point.
  Monsters cannot be Set, they must be Normal Summoned in Defense Position.*
- *You may only attack another Duelist if they are on the same lane as you and in front of you. Also, you can switch lanes in order to avoid attacks.*
- *You begin with 4000 Life Points, which are not restored after each Duel.*
- *Ramming your opponents is legal.*
- *A player may use their allies' monsters for a Fusion or Xyz Summon.*
- *Players may Set Spell and Trap Cards on the coaster in order to damage other players with their effects*

Does EDOPro suport this Duel Mode?

Comment: I apologize if Edopro isn't used inly in the OCG/OCG world.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I asked if you can play on EdoPro with the duel coasters feature.

Comment: @KMR Thank you very much for that revision; this clears up the question considerably!

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is **no**, *EDOPro doesn't support Duel Coasters.*

ProjectIgnis maintain a list of supported additional Duel Modes on their [github repo](https://github.com/ProjectIgnis/CardScripts/wiki/Extra-Rules), which is the best reference for what's supported, and doesn't include Duel Coasters.

That said it seems unlikely EDOPro will support Duel Coasters in future, as implementing the roller coaster mechanics would require an entirely different setup to regular duels.